# Unable to detect the correct character-encoding

Tags: c#, character-encoding, firebird, interbase, firebird2.5

I need to extract data from some old interbase databasefiles created with InterBase 4.2.1. I'm using the embedded version of Firebird (version 2.5.1) and the .NetProvider (version 2.7.0). I never worked with interbase of firebird before (but i have some experience with SQL SERVER and SQLite) and after cruising the web and experimenting for 2 days, I have yet to find a solution.

The tables in the database contain data in English, but also data in Hebrew. Optimistic as I was, I started by creating my connection string using UTF8:

```
FbConnectionStringBuilder builder = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.Database = m_DatabaseName;
builder.ServerType = FbServerType.Embedded;
builder.Charset = FbCharset.Utf8.ToString();
```

But that gave me the following exception:

```
bad parameters on attach or create database
CHARACTER SET Utf8 is not defined
```

I correctly used the fbintl.dll. (see the files in my application directory and subdirectories below). I even used ProcessMonitor to check if the fbintl.dll was loaded.

```
fbembed.dll
firebird.log
firebird.msg
FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll
ib_util.dll
icudt30.dll
icuin30.dll
icuuc30.dll
MyApplication.exe
Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest
msvcp80.dll
msvcr80.dll
intl\fbintl.conf
intl\fbintl.dll
udf\fbudf.dll
udf\ib_udf.dll
```

So I tried enumerating `FbCharset` and trying to connect with each character set, more than half of them threw the same exception, and when I connected with the others and queried one of the Hebrew fields (by using `IDataReader.GetString()`), I always got the same garbage as result. It doesn't seem to matter what character set I specify in the connection string, the result are always the same, even if I don't specify any character set at all.

Next I queried the character sets defined in the database `SELECT RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM RDB$CHARACTER_SETS` and I enumrated those, trying to connect with each one of them, some threw an exception, the others gave the same result as before.

I have no clue with what character set the database was created, but I checked the character sets of each field in the database and all text fields have their character sets set to 'NONE'.

```
SELECT r.RDB$RELATION_NAME, r.RDB$FIELD_NAME, f.RDB$FIELD_NAME, cset.RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME
FROM RDB$RELATION_FIELDS r
LEFT JOIN RDB$FIELDS f ON r.RDB$FIELD_SOURCE = f.RDB$FIELD_NAME
LEFT JOIN RDB$CHARACTER_SETS cset ON f.RDB$CHARACTER_SET_ID = cset.RDB$CHARACTER_SET_ID
ORDER BY r.RDB$RELATION_NAME ASC, r.RDB$FIELD_POSITION ASC
```

But I noticed some of the system tables' text fields have UNICODE_FSS as character set. I already tried that character set in the connection string, but I still get garbadge for the requested text fields.

My last try was to retrieve the bytes (by using `IDataReader.GetBytes()`) and encode the string myself, but this gives me a cast exception (`Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'.`)

Does anyone have any ideas on how to read this data ? I don't need to convert the databases permanently, as they won't be used anymore once i have extracted the data.

EDIT: btw, are there any free lightweight interbase/firebird database viewers, I can't seem to find any good ones (comparable to [SQLiteSpy](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/index)) ?

Marc

Comment: Try to convert the database into FB 2.5 format using http://gsbelarus.com/gs/fdbconvert/ FDBConvert utility.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it, it gave me an "unkown server type" error. I forgot to mention That I also tried the FBClone utility (http://code.google.com/p/fbclone/, version 2.1.4), and that didn't work either as my database doesn't seem to have the RDB$FIELDS.RDB$FIELD_PRECISION. I think the interbase version used to created these databases is too old for these utilities.

Comment: If you interested I have IB 4.2 installation. I think the better approach would be to upgrade database through backup-restore sequence up to FB 1.0 version and then convert it to 2.5 using FDBConvert utility.

Comment: I have the 4.2.1 instalation myself, but I'm not looking forward to install such an old software ( does it even run on win7 x64?) And I don't know the username/password used to create the DB (not needed for embedded).  And can you import a DB in an embedded FB1.0 or do I need to install a server aswell ? (same question, does it run on win7, as I see a Vista warning on the site) Besides, I need to convert a lot of these databases, I'm not looking forward to all these manual actions. Is there no way to read the varchar fields as bytes, so I can convert them in c# ?

Comment: Try to connect to database using IBExpert. It has a function of data export. If it will not help, I'm afraid you will need to go through database upgrade cycle. i.e. backup up it on IB 4.2.1 server and then restore with FB 1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution.

The original database was written on a windows with codepage 1255. When I read the data now c# generates a unicode string using the default encoding (which is not 1255). So i just decode the string to bytes using the default encoding and then convert the bytes to string using the correct encoding.

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);
...
if (!datareader.IsDBNull(i))
{
    string value = dataReader.GetString(i);
    if (value.Length > 0)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value);
        value = encoding.GetString(bytes);
    }
    // store value
 }
```

This solution works fine for me, but I still don't understand why I can't specify "WIN1255" as charset in my connectionstring without getting the exception `bad parameters on attach or create database - CHARACTER SET WIN1255 is not defined` ? (I even tried charset "WINDOWS1255" but then i get the exception `Invalid character set specified`).